# Audioplayer using progress bar with a readfile output

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio-streaming

I'm facing a problem. I would like to play audio files in my website but without possibilities of downloading them. To do that, I use a token method to disable the copy paste method to download. But because of that I have to use the php readfile() function. The problem is that with this the file is read into a buffer so for now I cannot go to the time I want by clicking to the progress bar, only go to the end of the buffer... 
I don't know if it is the token method that is not good or if it exists an alternative to the readfile function. 
This is why I need your help :)

I working with Shopware Framework. Basically, it will know automatically what page to launch according to php function. Here it is the part page that import the import function into the audio player.

```
PHP


// Mainly this is listing the several files of the article and create the token

public function indexAction(){
        $id = (int) $this->Request()->getParam('sArticle');
        $userData = $this->admin->sGetUserData();
        $userID = $userData['additional']['user']['id'];
        $testAuthorized = Shopware()->Db()->fetchAll("
                            SELECT *
                            FROM s_articles_esd as ae, s_order_esd as oe
                            WHERE oe.userID = $userID AND ae.articleID = $id AND oe.esdID = ae.id
                                              ");
        if(!$testAuthorized){
            return $this->redirect(
              array('controller' => 'streaming',
                    'action' => 'error')
            );
        }

        $answer = Shopware()->Db()->fetchAll("
                            SELECT ad.ordernumber, a.name, aa.oa_toc
                            FROM s_articles_details as ad, s_articles as a, s_articles_attributes as aa
                            WHERE a.id = $id AND ad.articleID = a.id AND aa.articledetailsID = ad.id AND ad.additionaltext='MP3'
                                              ")[0];
        $orderNumber = $answer['ordernumber'];
        $name = $answer['name'];
        $inhalt = $answer['oa_toc'];

        $files_folder = "files/".Shopware()->Config()->get('sESDKEY')."/";
        $files = glob($files_folder.$orderNumber."/*.mp3", GLOB_BRACE);
        $nb_files = count($files);

        $pdf_files = glob($files_folder.$orderNumber."/*.pdf", GLOB_BRACE);
        $pdf_files_res = array();

        foreach($pdf_files as $file){
            array_push($pdf_files_res, basename($file));
        }

        $this->View()->assign('files', gettype($files[0]));
        $this->View()->assign('files_folder', $files_folder);
        $this->View()->assign('orderNumber', $orderNumber);
        $this->View()->assign('nb_files', $nb_files);
        $this->View()->assign('pdf_files', $pdf_files_res);
        $this->View()->assign('name', $name);
        $this->View()->assign('inhalt', $inhalt);

        $this->View()->assign('sUserLoggedIn', $this->admin->sCheckUser());

        if ($this->isOneTimeAccount()) {
            $this->logoutAction();
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'register']);
        }
    }


//This function will check if the token exist ad then play the code
public function partAction(){
        $id = $this->Request()->getParam('sArticle');
        $userData = $this->admin->sGetUserData();
        $userID = $userData['additional']['user']['id'];
        $part = $this->Request()->getParam('file');
        $orderNumber = $this->Request()->getParam('orderNumber');
        $testAuthorized = Shopware()->Db()->fetchAll("
                            SELECT *
                            FROM s_order_esd as oe, s_order_details as ad
                            WHERE oe.userID = $userID AND ad.articleordernumber = '$orderNumber' AND oe.orderdetailsID = ad.id
                                              ");
        if(!$testAuthorized){
            return $this->redirect(
              array('controller' => 'streaming',
                    'action' => 'error')
            );
        }

        $files_folder = "files/".Shopware()->Config()->get('sESDKEY')."/";
        $files = glob($files_folder.$orderNumber."/*.mp3", GLOB_BRACE);

        $file = $files[$part - 1];

        $token = uniqid(rand(), true);

        Shopware()->Db()->query("
                    INSERT INTO s_files_tokens
                    SET token='$token', file_name='$file'");
        $this->View()->assign('file', $file);
        $this->View()->assign('token', $token);
        $this->View()->assign('part', $part);
    }
```

```
HTML with Smarty
import.tpl

<style>
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
      audio{
          width: 100%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 500px) {
      audio{
          width: 500px;
      }
    }
</style>

{* Audio player *}
<audio id="player" controls="" preload="auto" controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src='{url controller="streaming" action="import" token="`$token`"}' type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```